# Slick — Complete failed transactional action with intermediate result

Tags: scala, transactions, slick

I'm trying to use transactions in Slick to ease setup and teardown of the database state for some integration tests I'm writing. The code looks something like this:

```
val actions = for {
  _    <- setUpTables
  data <- readDataWeWantToAssertOn
  _    <- DBIO.failed(new RuntimeException("ROLLBACK"))
} yield {
  data
}

db.run(actions.transactionally).map { data =>
  asset(data.size == 1)
}
```

I'm using a DB rollback to reset the database state. However, my problem is that I don't know how to roll back that sequence of actions, while still yielding the intermediate database results that have been read while within the transaction.

I have a workaround that uses `scala.concurrent.Promise` to "push" the intermediate result there, but I was wondering if there's any way to do this using Slick.

I've also looked at the `andFinally` and `cleanUp` combinators, which ignore the last result and yield the penultimate one, but that only applies when the last action is not an error, which in my case needs to be an error so that the transaction is rolled back.